# Having some troubles with file locks under Linux

Tags: c, linux, schedule, flock, fcntl

My English is poor so you may get confused from my description below.
In Linux, multiple processes were requesting a file lock (flock or fcntl lock), then the previous exclusive file lock was released. I think which process can gain the lock is random (not specified).
But every time I try, it always seems like in FIFO (like the following photo). (And I have already tried many times).
I want to figure out is something wrong with my code or anything else?

```
#include <sys/file.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "tlpi_hdr.h"

char *currTime(const char *format);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int fd;
    struct flock fl;

    fd = open("./file", O_RDWR); /* Open file to be locked */
    if (fd == -1)
        errExit("open");

    fl.l_len = 0;
    fl.l_start = 0;
    fl.l_whence = SEEK_SET;
    fl.l_type = F_WRLCK;

    if (fcntl(fd, F_SETLKW, &fl) == -1)
    {
        if (errno == EAGAIN || errno == EACCES)
            printf("already locked");
        else if (errno == EDEADLK)
            printf("dead lock");
        else
            errExit("fcntl");
    }
    else
        printf("PID %ld: have got write lock at %s\n", (long)getpid(), currTime("%T"));

    sleep(atoi(argv[1]));

    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS); // close fd and this cause unlock flock's lock
}
```

[image]

Comment: If the order is not specified, that doesn't mean it's forced to be random, just that you can't depend on any particular order. It might be FIFO just because that's the easiest way to code it in the kernel.

Comment: Please don't put images, https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question